# How to calculate all-rounder in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like this

```
studentID subjectID subjectMark subjectWeight  Rank   overallScore 

 1         111         100         0.4           3      40      
 1         222         0           0.6           3      40   
 2         111         90          0.4           1      90      
 2         222         90          0.6           1      90     
 3         111         0           0.4           2      60      
 3         222         100         0.6           2      60
```

as you can see, student 1 and 3, each of them achieved very high score in certain subjects but their overall scores are bad whereas student 2 did not get any highest mark in any subject but has the best overall score

overallScore = subject111Mark * subject111Weight + subject222Mark * subject222Weight

so I want to see if a certain student is an "all-rounder", meaning I wanna see if this student has the highest overall score **but** do not have any highest score in any subject. if this condition is met label this student as "all-rounder"

and df should look like this:

```
studentID subjectID subjectMark subjectWeight  Rank   overallScore AR

 1         111         100         0.4           3      40         F
 1         222         0           0.6           3      40         F
 2         111         90          0.4           1      90         T
 2         222         90          0.6           1      90         T
 3         111         0           0.4           2      60         F
 3         222         100         0.6           2      60         F
```

I have a follow-up question 
the answer given can do the trick for last dataframe, but what if I want to do that for every class in the following dataframe?

```
studentID subjectID subjectMark subjectWeight  Rank   overallScore classID

 1         111         100         0.4           3      40         1
 1         222         0           0.6           3      40         1
 2         111         90          0.4           1      90         1
 2         222         90          0.6           1      90         1
 3         111         0           0.4           2      60         1
 3         222         100         0.6           2      60         1
 4         444         95          0.4           3      38         2
 4         555         0           0.6           3      38         2
 5         444         90          0.4           1      90         2
 5         555         90          0.6           1      90         2
 6         444         0           0.4           2      57         2
 6         555         95          0.6           2      57         2
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of code to reproduce your situation please?

Comment: With your logic, you will only ever label at most a single student as an `all-rounder` in your entire dataset (and likely no one at all). Is this what you actually want?

Answer (score 2):

You may check

```
s1=df.groupby('subjectID').subjectMark.transform('max').eq(df.subjectMark)# check the max score with each student 
s2=df.overallScore.eq(df.overallScore.max())# get the max score of overall
s2&((~s1).groupby(df['studentID']).transform('all'))# get the above conditions and both met should return True
Out[1066]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: you are legendary!

Comment: would you pls kindly explain what exactly does (~ s1).groupby(data['studentID']).transform('all') do? I cannot really understand.
i know ~s1 is the opposite of s1

Comment: @JuniorAngelo to get all of student's subject is not the highest

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_all_rounder_per_class = []

for classid in data['classID'].unique():
    that_class = data.loc[data.classID == classID]
    condition1 = that_class.groupby(['subjectID']).subjectMark.transform('max').eq(that_class.subjectMark) 
    condition2 = that_class.overallScore.eq(that_class. overallScore.max()) 
    # get the above conditions and both met should return True
    list_of_all_rounder_per_class.append(condition2 &((~condition1).groupby(that_class['studentID']).transform('all')))

total_result = [result_for_each_class.to_frame('all_rounder') for result_for_each_class in list_of_all_rounder_per_class]
all_rounder = pd.concat(total_result)

data = data.join(all_rounder, how='outer')
```

I have figure out a way to work around it, even though it might be the best(cleanest) way to achieve the goal